# Why ComboBox Loded a Different Value In WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I have an Employee Class That Contains two Property Id and Name.I was trying To show them in ComboBox and made a click event To show the Selected Item Through message box. The Click Event Is Working fine it shows me the correct value but in combobox it shows me the diffrent value. I am a newb in WPF MVVM. This is my EmployeeModelView Class

```
class EmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return employee;
        }

        set
        {
            employee = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Employee> employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
    {
        new Employee {Id=1,Name="asdasd"},
        new Employee { Id=2,Name="wwerewr"}
    };

    private Employee selectedEmployee;
    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedEmployee;
        }

        set
        {
            selectedEmployee = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        }
    }
```

This is my View

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmployee"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

I get this Output 
[image]

This is my main Window Code

```
EmployeeViewModel emps;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        emps = new EmployeeViewModel();
        this.DataContext = emps;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Employee emp = emps.SelectedEmployee;
        MessageBox.Show(emp.Id + " " + emp.Name);
    }
```

Comment: You would usually only show the value of the Name property in the ComboBox. Instead of an ItemTemplate, you may then just set `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` on the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Have you tried to use `DisplayMemberPath` attribute to your `ComboBox`?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmployee"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
```

It shows the `Name` of the `Employee` in the `Combo`.

**Solution 2:**

It's better to override `ToString` of `Employee`

```
public class Employee{
    public override string ToString(){
        return $"{Id} {Name}"; 
    }
}
```

Like this, your combo will show the text as you want. And it make more clair in `button_Click`

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(emps.SelectedEmployee?.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: yea it worked Thanks. Can you suggest me show a list of names in the combobox without creating the employee every time like this

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Employee> employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
    {
        new Employee {Id=1,Name="asdasd"},
        new Employee { Id=2,Name="wwerewr"}
    };

Comment: Who voted this down? These are exactly the correct solutions. No need to go sacrificing performance for more complexity unless you have good reason to.

Comment: @MarkFeldman maybe some developers want to use `ItemTemplace` for display.. My answer about ToString is correct but it changes everything.

Comment: @ShantoSiddiq why you create manually your list. Populate it from the database?

Comment: I also think that it is a good option. I used DataTemplate because he didn't specified that he needed just name in combobox. @ThierryV I upvoted your answer because it also very good.

Comment: @Babbillumpa thanks for support me :) . Your idea abt ItemTempalte is good too. 1+ for you

Comment: @Thierry V I don't want to populate it from the database for the time being. I was trying to implement two comboBox that is generated from a same list and after a click event it should generate different result. Any suggestion would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set ComboBox ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmployee"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">

 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <WrapPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
       </WrapPanel>                
   </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```